# pyodbc in Airflow works in CLI but fails when running DAG from UI

Tags: python, airflow, pyodbc, impala

I have a simple DAG which runs kinit to establish a kerberos ticket and then uses pyodbc to connect to a db engine (impala) and run a select count(*) query.

```
CONN_ARGS = {
'Driver':LINKTODRIVER,
'HOST':HOST, 
'PORT':PORT,
'AuthMech':'1',
'KrbFQDN':HOST,
'KrbRealm':'SOME.REALM',
'KrbServiceName':'servicename',
'SSL':1,
'autocommit':True
}


def run_test_two():
   conn = pyodbc.connect(**CONN_ARGS)
   statement = 'SELECT count(*) AS result FROM some.table'
   crsr = conn.cursor()
   crsr.execute(statement)
   print(crsr.fetchall())
   conn.close()  


with DAG (
   dag_id ='test_dag',
   schedule_interval=None, #only for manual test runs
   start_date=datetime(2022, 1, 1),
   catchup=False,
   description='This is a test dag',
   dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=60)
) as dag:

   task_test_task_one = BashOperator(
       task_id='test_task_one',
       bash_command=KINIT_TASK_COMMAND,
       dag=dag
   )

   task_test_task_two = PythonOperator(
       task_id='test_task_two',
       python_callable=run_test_two,
       dag=dag
   )


   task_test_task_one >> task_test_task_two
```

When running the DAG in the CLI everything works, but when I run the DAG from the UI I get an access issue:

```
pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', '[HY000] [Cloudera][DriverSupport] (1170) Unexpected response 
received from server. Please ensure the server host and port specified for the 
connection are correct. (1170) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

What is the Airflow UI doing differently from the CLI to cause this issue?

Comment: Please, confirm that the script you run from CLI is deployed on the same VM where airflow is deployed.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes it is. 
I should add that this has been tested on two different instances of airflow with the same behaviour experienced.

Comment: And are you running airflow on docker or directly on VM?

Comment: Directly on VM. We have also tried it via docker with same result.

Comment: Is Impala deployed on docker?

Comment: No, impala is not deployed on docker. But again - the connection works fine from CLI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out - although the kinit task succeeds, because of the way airflow works (launching tasks in separate worker pods) the 'kinit' does not exist in the subsequent task. From the CLI it works because the same session is essentially open, so the kinit still exists, but in the UI that session is closed before the next task executes.

**Adding the kinit into the same task as the pyodbc connection fixed the problem.**